# Detox get length of element

Tags: react-native, e2e-testing, detox

Hi i'm using detox and i would like to know how can I get the number of matches to
one element(length).

For example "card" match three times, how can I get the three.

```
const z = await element(by.id("card"))
```

https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.Expect.md
https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.Matchers.md

They don't support it in the API /:

z output:

```
Element {
  _invocationManager: InvocationManager {
    executionHandler: Client {
      isConnected: true,
      configuration: [Object],
      ws: [AsyncWebSocket],
      slowInvocationStatusHandler: null,
      slowInvocationTimeout: undefined,
      successfulTestRun: true,
      pandingAppCrash: undefined
    }
  },
  matcher: Matcher { predicate: { type: 'id', value: 'card' } }
}
```

Comment: Can you log z and tell me it's contents? Is it an array?

Comment: @PLASMA chicken, Thanks i updated my question, and I didn't saw array.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround could be

```
async function getMatchesLength(elID) {
    let index = 0;

    try {
        while (true) {
            await expect(element(by.id(elID)).atIndex(index)).toExist();
            index++;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('find ', index, 'matches');
    }

    return index;
}
```

then you can use

```
const length = await getMatchesLength('card');
jestExpect(length).toBe(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution in typescript:

```
async function elementCount(matcher: Detox.NativeMatcher) {
  const attributes = await element(matcher).getAttributes();

  // If the query matches multiple elements, the attributes of all matched elements is returned as an array of objects under the elements key.
  https://wix.github.io/Detox/docs/api/actions-on-element/#getattributes
  if ("elements" in attributes) {
    return attributes.elements.length;
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
const jestExpect = require("expect");

jestExpect(await elementCount(by.id("some-id"))).toBe(2);
```

Comment: This might have been different in the past, it looks like accessing a `length` property is android-only now.
https://wix.github.io/Detox/docs/api/actions/#getattributes